# Is there a way to see binding traces in -design- mode?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, data-binding

I can set the trace using code such as:

`xmlns:trace="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
trace:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High`

I can also set the debug settings in Options->Debugging->Output Window->Data Binding.

But I cannot see the trace information as it occurs in design-time.

You might ask why I want to do this.  The design-time execution is not the same as the runtime execution, even when I have made the best effort to keep things running the same way.  Seeing these traces would be a huge help.

Comment: anyone? This is really getting to be a headache.